# How to catch two different values of the same predicate in sparql?

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

In my turtle file I have 2 lines with the same predicate, but different values:

```
1_schema:hasObject  <http://dzx/op/P007865> ;
1_schema:hasObject  <http://dzx/op/P001176> ;
```

I'm using the following to retrieve both values:

```
   SELECT ?result
    FROM <urn:graph>
    WHERE 
    { ?s <http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier> ?identifier.
    OPTIONAL { ?s <http://xxx#hasObject ?result .}
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting only **one** result from two expected http://dzx/op/P007865 http://dzx/op/P001176

Comment: that are two different predicates if you look at the prefixes of the predicates

Comment: @UninformedUser  I've corrected it, predicates should be the same

Comment: please show the complete data, it's impossible to get only one binding 1) if the same subject is used with 2) the same predicate and 3) there is no `limit 1` in the query and 4) the data has been loaded into the same graph

Comment: it was limit 1 in the query that I had to remove. thanks!

Comment: Please update your question and include the full query.